# (FIXED) Reopen gitea PR that was accidentally closed

Tags: gitea

Is it possible to reopen a PR that was accidentally closed the branch? I think it’s because the branch marked as deleted in the PR even though I can see it in the list of branches on the code tab. When I click Edit next to the PR name I cannot select a different branch in the “pull from:” drop down.

EDIT:

I was able to force push the sha in gitea-repo/repo/refs/pull/PRNUM to the original branch. That allowed me to reopen the PR. Then I pushed the new sha.

Comment: Can you run git branch in the command-line of the folder?

Comment: @LajosArpad I figured it out. See OP